# Why was the Devil/Satan not chained and kept in darkness like the other fallen angels mentioned in Jude 1:6 and 2 Peter 2:4?

Tags: revelation, job, eschatology, 2-peter, jude

We are told that after Satan/devil and his angels had been cast down onto the earth he went to fight against the woman and later her offspring. This seems to point to a being that was free to do as he wills.

Yet according to Jude and Peter's narrative, the angels that left their own position of authority which would include Satan were chained in darkness until the day of judgment.

Jude 1:6 ESV

> 6 And the angels who did not stay within their own position of authority, but left their proper dwelling, he has kept in ***eternal chains under gloomy darkness*** until the judgment of the great day.

Peter also reiterates the same position concerning these fallen angels

2 Peter 2:4 ESV

> 4 For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but cast them into hell[a] and ***committed them to chains[b] of gloomy darkness*** to be kept until the judgment;

But the Devil/Satan who seemingly led this rebellion is cast down onto the earth to roam freely to and fro. It seems he is not restricted in any of his movements because he is seen fighting the woman and later her offspring.

Revelation 12:9 ESV

> 9 And the great dragon was thrown down, that ancient serpent, who is called the devil and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world—***he was thrown down to the earth, and his angels were thrown down with him***

> 17 ***Then the dragon became furious with the woman and went off to make war on the rest of her offspring***, on those who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus. And he stood[c] on the sand of the sea.

Later again he is seen going after Job tormenting him and giving him a torrid time

Job 1:6-7 ESV

> 6 Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan[b] also came among them. 7 The Lord said to Satan, “From where have you come?” Satan answered the Lord and said, ***“From going to and fro on the earth***, and from walking up and down on it.

It is only later in the book of Revelation that the Devil/Satan is chained so that he will no longer deceive the nations

Revelation 20:3 ESV

> ***3 and threw him into the pit, and shut it and sealed it over him***, so that he might not deceive the nations any longer, until the thousand years were ended. After that he must be released for a little while.

Why was the Devil/Satan not chained and kept in darkness like those angels mentioned in Jude and 2 Peter 2?

Comment: Enoch is a [type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typology_(theology)) of Christ (see also John 3:13); similarly, Elijah is a type of John the Baptist (Matthew 11:13-14, 17:12-13, Luke 1:17).

Comment: Being confined to the earth is equivalent to being chained in darkness.  Satan shared the same fete.

Comment: You said ‘*seemingly*’ Satan led a rebellion? I’m aware of the [unsubstantiated - no biblical evidence for this] ‘speculation’ of this alleged event. And if  not for that event, for what other reason should he be chained? (and incidentally there is *no* biblical evidence that he was an ‘angel’. But - Yes, a spiritual ‘entity’)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why was the Devil/Satan not chained and kept in darkness like those angels mentioned in Jude and 2 Peter 2?**

Simply because he still had a role to fulfil in God's plan of salvation. The time would come when Satan would be banished from the realm of men and returned for one final period of temptation.

> he took hold of the dragon,... Satan, and bound him for a thousand years ... so that he would not deceive the nations any longer, until the thousand years were completed; after these things he must be released for a short time. Rev 20:2-3

> When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison, 8and will come out to deceive the nations which are at the four corners of the earth... v7

God has used evil for His purposes since the garden when the serpent was present. Clearly, God could have chosen another route for His new creation, but He did not. He could have banished the 'serpent' to another galaxy, but He did not.

> No one is to say when he is tempted, “I am being tempted by God”; for God cannot be tempted by evil, and He Himself does not tempt anyone. James 1:13

> Submit yourselves, then, to God. Resist the devil, and he will flee from you. 4:7

We should not take the "eternal chains under gloomy darkness" too literally. Just as we read of Satan being thrown into the fires - no fire would bother a spirit being, so we have to see these prophecies with some careful consideration by referring to other texts in concert.

Comment: ,whether the chains are taken literally or otherwise the end results is the same,the devil was restricted by being bound and thrown into the pit. which stopped him from deceiving the nations for awhile

Comment: The chains (in my ref.) refer to the angels = perhaps they are still active and the "chains" are not literally *holding them captive* and doing nothing.

Comment: ,what bound the devil and restricted him from deceiving the nations?

Comment: Curious? - where are you Founding that claim that God needs Satan to ‘help him’ achieve salvation for man?

Comment: I think the last two references support sufficiently.  Without a tree to blow against, is there any wind?

Comment: @steveowen There is wind in the treeless desert.  Are you suggesting God created evil so that good could be recognized?  Also *no fire would bother a spirit being*? ... The lake of fire was prepared for spirit beings (Matt. 25:41) and they are tormented there (Rev. 20:10) which I assume bothers them.

Answer (score 2):

Jude 1:

> 6 And the **angels** who did not stay within their own position of authority, but left their proper dwelling, he has kept in eternal chains under gloomy darkness until the judgment of the great day.

Jude does not say for all angels and did not specifically mention Satan or the devil.
Neither does Peter in
2 Peter 2:

> 4 For if God did not spare **angels** when they sinned, but cast them into hell and committed them to chains of gloomy darkness to be kept until the judgment;

OP: Yet according to Jude and Peter's narrative the angels that left their own position of authority which would include Satan were chained in darkness until the day of judgement

Strictly speaking, this is not necessarily true according to first-order logic for-all. The universal quantifier is missing in these verses. This bears out in
Revelation 12:

> 9 And the great **dragon** was thrown down, that ancient serpent, who is called the devil and **Satan**, the deceiver of the whole world—he was thrown down to the earth, and his angels were thrown down with him

> 17 Then the **dragon** became furious with the woman and went off to make war on the rest of her offspring, on those who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus. And he stood on the sand of the sea.

Apparently, the dragon/Satan is not bound in chains. He is capable of movement and traveling.

Why was the Devil/Satan not chained and kept in darkness like those angels mentioned in Jude and 2 Peter 2?

So that he could continue to tempt people. It's God's will that people be tested for their faith in this life.

Answer (score 1):

> Jude 1:6 And the angels which kept not their first estate, but left their own habitation, he hath reserved in everlasting chains under darkness unto the judgment of the great day.

> 2Pe 2:4 For if God spared not the angels that sinned, but cast them down to hell, and delivered them into chains of darkness, to be reserved unto judgment;

The chain or the restraint in both verses is the "Darkness".

Jesus refers to Himself as light.

> Joh 8:12 ¶ Then spake Jesus again unto them, saying, I am the light of the world: he that followeth me shall not walk in darkness, but shall have the light of life.

The concept of "light" was not a physical condition of Jesus or his followers while they were on earth. In John 8:12 Jesus referred to a spiritual condition which a person was aware of and existed within.

Being reserved for Judgment does not necessarily mean that they are individuals waiting for their personal judgment. The existence in the condition of "Darkness" is the result of God's Judgement.

Being "reserved" for the purpose of "Judgment" suggests that these disobedient spiritual beings inflict the darkness they exist in upon disobedient people.

The Devil and his Angels exist in darkness. Not physical restraints.

Exposure to them can be prohibited by God as a sign of His approval.

> Pr 16:7 ¶ When a man's ways please the LORD, he maketh even his enemies to be at peace with him.

Exposure to them can be allowed by God to indicate His disapproval. This fits with the concept of the Devils role as "tempter".

> Mt 4:3 And when the tempter came to him, he said, If thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.

Answer (score 0):

It is imperative that we begin with an understanding of the OT prophetic language and its metaphors.  The NT prophesy is in the same style.  Without the knowledge of the OT prophetic uses, the NT becomes twisted and misunderstood.

In OT prophesy, the word "heavens" was often used for the ruling places and positions of kings and governors.  In Deu. 32:1, Moses began the prophesy of the destruction of Israel for their sins, and relayed the words of the Lord, *"Give ear, O ye heavens, and I will speak; and hear, O earth, the words of my mouth."*

God was not talking to himself, calling upon His heaven to hear.  He was speaking to the ruling classes and to the people under those rulers in Israel.  Isaiah did the same as he began the prophesy to the people.

> *"Hear, O heavens, and give ear, O earth: for the Lord hath spoken, I have nourished and brought up children, and they have rebelled against me."*  (Isa. 1:2, KJV)

The heavens were the king and his court, and all of his princes and governors that ruled over his kingdom.  The earth were the people of that land in that specific kingdom.  In prophetic language, falling to earth, or being thrown down to earth was the same as saying those rulers were being removed from their positions of authority.  They lost their status, and their power.

The heavenly places were the kings' palaces and lands where they ruled and held dominion.  His kingdom was a type of heaven. Just as God's kingdom and rule is over all the earth, David's kingdom was a subset of God's kingdom that He allowed David to have dominion over a part of the earth.  So, David's kingdom was David's heaven of his rule and authority.

We must also consider that the word translated in the English as "angel" is actually "aggelos" in the Greek, and should rightly be translated as messenger. ([aggelos](https://biblehub.com/greek/32.htm))  There are heavenly messengers such as Gabriel, and there are human messengers such as the prophets Isaiah, Malachi, Jeremiah and John the Immerser, and the Apostles.  A messenger is anyone that is tasked with sending the message and God used both heavenly and human messengers.

People wrongly assume that the messengers of Jude 1:6, and 2 Pet. 2:4 are speaking of heavenly messengers.  But, when we read further to 2 Pet. 2:11 there is a distinction between the messengers of vs. 4 and those of vs. 11 who are greater in power.  Messengers who are greater in power are the heavenly messengers.  2 Pet. 2:4 and Jude 1:6 are referring to the human messengers who did not keep their assigned places / jobs and who did not do the will of the Father.  They were most probably those Levitical priests who led the people astray.

Putting this all into the context of Rev. 12 requires the time elements be observed.  Rev. 12 begins with a back flash image where Christ is showing John things which had already happened in the 1st century AD with the killing of the children under Herod and the attempt to kill the Christ child (vs. 4, 5) and then moving forward in time to the collective woman of the church of Christ's saints who would have to flee to the wilderness for 1260 days (vs. 6).

This ties the events to the 1st century AD.  The woman was both Mary, the mother of Christ, and the church of His saints.  Both were pursued by the dragon, or the devil, which in the Greek means a false accuser.  The old serpent from the garden was still active and using the power of the Roman emperors - seven heads and ten horns, vs. 3 - to carry out his war against God and Christ.

The war in heaven of vs. 7 was both spiritual and earthly.  The spiritual struggle between God and the old serpent for God's plan of salvation through His Son Yeshua (Jesus) was being waged out on the earth of the Roman empire and the Sanhedrin council in Jerusalem.  The heaven where the war took place was not in God's heaven above, but in the heaven of the king's / emperor's earthly dominion where "hasatan" always interfered in the affairs of men.

Michael - the prefigured Christ of the OT - and His messengers - Jesus' disciples and apostles - were battling the full council of the Sanhedrin - the dragon - which was in turn backed by the full power of the heaven of the Roman empire.  The dragon lost that battle, and those rulers whom he used were thrown down from their positions of authority.

At the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem in AD 70, the power of the holy people - the Jews - was shattered (Dan. 12:6-7).  They no longer held the authority or power to persecute the saints, and would have no power to prevent the gospel of Christ from spreading throughout the entire earth.

I do believe that the old serpent from the garden was thrown into the lake of fire at that time.  Most people want to attribute all the sin in the world to that old serpent.  But we don't need to blame him.  As all evil comes from within the heart of man (Lev. 18:30; Matt. 15:19-20; Mark 7:21-23) men are fully to blame for all the evil actions they conceive.

That battle of Rev. 12 finished the war between the devil and God for the rule of all the earth and all of mankind.  The devil was judged and defeated. God won.  Christ won.  And, all who have answered the call of the gospel of Christ are the beneficiaries.

Answer (score 0):

##### Why was Satan not chained and kept in darkness like the other fallen angels?

TL;DR: He *was*.

The angels were there when God created the world:

> while the morning stars sang together and all the angels[sons of God] shouted for joy
> — Job 38:7 (NIV)

They had access to both God's spirit Heaven and the physical universe.

Lucifer and his angels later rebelled against God:

> How you have **fallen from heaven**, morning star, son of the dawn! You have been **cast down to the earth**, you who once laid low the nations!
> You said in your heart, “I will ascend to the heavens; I will raise my throne above the stars of God; I will sit enthroned on the mount of assembly, on the utmost heights of Mount Zaphon.
> I will ascend above the tops of the clouds; I will make myself like the Most High.”
> But you are brought down to the realm of the dead, to the depths of the pit.
> — Isaiah 14:12–15

So they were banned from Heaven and the rest of creation, forced to inhabit Earth:

> For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but sent them to hell [Tartarus], putting them in chains of darkness to be held for judgment
> — 2 Peter 2:4

Compared to what they previously had, being confined to Earth *is* like chains of darkness, separated from the rest of creation, separated from Heaven, separated from God.

At times God might summon them into his presence:

> One day the angels came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them.
> The LORD said to Satan, “Where have you come from?” Satan answered the LORD, “From roaming throughout the earth, going back and forth on it.”
> — Job 1:6–7

Here, Satan could be complaining that he has been pacing back and forth in his confinement on Earth, like a prisoner in a small cell.

And soon, Satan will be further confined for the duration of the Millennium, so that he no longer has access to even the Earth:

> He seized the dragon, that ancient serpent, who is the devil, or Satan, and bound him for a thousand years.
> He threw him into the Abyss, and locked and sealed it over him, to keep him from deceiving the nations anymore until the thousand years were ended. After that, he must be set free for a short time.
> — Revelation 20:2–3

Satan will be briefly released during the day of judgement:

> When the thousand years are over, Satan will be released from his prison and will go out to deceive the nations in the four corners of the earth …
> — Revelation 20:7–8

But finally Satan will be permanently destroyed (or confined):

> … fire came down from heaven and devoured them.
> And the devil, who deceived them, was thrown into the lake of burning sulfur …
> — Revelation 20:9–10